# Make a two-digit string from a single-digit integer

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, nsstring, number-formatting

How can I have a two-digit integer in a a string, even if the integer is less than 10?

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 1] //should be @"01"
```

Answer (score 307, accepted):

I believe that the stringWithFormat specifiers are the standard [IEEE printf specifiers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html). Have you tried

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", 1];
```

Comment: love it... 2 years in iphone and now i know this...thanks mate

Answer (score 27):

Use the format string `%02d`. This specifies to format an integer with a minimum field-width of 2 characters and to pad the formatted values with 0 to meet that width. See `man fprintf` for all the gory details of format specifiers.

If you are formatting numbers for presentation to the user, though, you should really be using `NSNumberFormatter`. Different locales have wildly different expectations about how numbers should be formatted.

Answer (score -3):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%00.02d", intValue]
```

This help me to convert 1 to 01.